# find unique characters in 2 strings

Tags: python

I am writing a python code to find the common characters in 2 strings.
Following is the code:

```
class CharactersInString:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def find_chars_order_n(self):
        new_string = [ ]
        new_string1 = " "
        new_value1 = list(self.value1)
        new_value2 = list(self.value2)
        print( "new_value1: ", new_value1)
        print( "new_value2: ", new_value2)
        for i in new_value1:
            if i in new_value2:
                new_string.append(i)
        print(new_string)
        new_list = set(new_string)
        final_list = list(new_list)
        print(final_list)
        print(''.join(final_list))

if __name__ == "__main__":
     obj = CharactersInString("hello manzer", "helzo killmse")
     print(obj.find_chars_order_n())
```

Desired output is `helo mz`. The above code gives me the output as `elzohm`. I want to get the unique characters and also,the order of the characters should be maintained as per value1.Using `SET` does not provide a ordered set. I am new to python. Could you please help me how to get the desired output and maintain the order of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition to see if the letter is there inside the list  before apppending it.

Try below code:

```
class CharactersInString:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def find_chars_order_n(self):
        new_string = []
        # new_value1 = list(self.value1)
        # new_value2 = list(self.value2)
        # print( "new_value1: ", new_value1)
        # print( "new_value2: ", new_value2)
        for i in self.value1:
            if i in self.value2 and i not in new_string:
                new_string.append(i)
        # print(new_string)
        # new_list = set(new_string)
        final_list = list(new_string)
        # print(final_list)
        return ''.join(final_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     obj = CharactersInString("hello manzer", "helzo killmse")
     print(obj.find_chars_order_n())
```

Output:

```
helo mz
```

Since we are iterating over value1, so we are sure that the order will be according to value1. Also, we are not at all adding a repeated value by checking with `i not in new_string`, so it should be better than "appending" and then removing using a set.

Answer (score 0):

Since dict keys follow their insertion order since Python 3.7, you can use the keys created from the `dict.fromkeys` method to effectively created an ordered set of `value1`, so that you can then iterate over this ordered set to test if each character is in `value2`, which can be converted to a set first for *O(1)* lookup time complexity, resulting in an overall time complexity of *O(n)*:

```
def CharactersInString(value1, value2):
    set2 = set(value2)
    return ''.join(c for c in dict.fromkeys(value1) if c in set2)
```

so that:

```
CharactersInString("hello manzer", "helzo killmse")
```

returns: `'helo mze'`

Or if you don't mind using the dunder method `set.__contains__` to test membership:

```
def CharactersInString(value1, value2):
    return ''.join(filter(set(value2).__contains__, dict.fromkeys(value1)))
```

Note that you can use `collections.OrderedDict` in place if `dict` if you're using an older Python version.

Answer (score 0):

> also,the order of the characters should be maintained as per value1.Using SET does not provide a ordered set.

You can write much simpler code by just re-ordering the set contents afterwards:

```
def unique_in_order_of_first(first, second):
    unique = set(first).intersection(second)
    return ''.join(sorted(unique, key=first.index))
```

Comment: This costs *O(n ^ 2 log n)* in average time complexity due to the use of the `sorted` function (which costs *O(n log n)*) and the `str.index` method (which costs *O(n)* for each item being sorted).